# CSS Flex one children top another bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I trying to do is make `a` element be on top and `button` be on bottom, without use `absolute` or `fix` position, just with `flex` is there any solution for this? Already `button` is on bottom but `title` not in top:

```css
.all {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
}
.element1 {
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
}
.element2 {
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
}
#details {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: self-end;
}
#details a {
    width: 100%;
}
#details button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="element1"></div>
  <div class="element2">
    <div id="details">
      <a>title</a>
      <button>Add TO Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `flex` on both childrens and use `align-self`, first `flex-start`, then `flex-end`

```css
.all {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
}
.element1 {
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
}
.element2 {
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
}
#details {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
#details a {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
#details button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="element1"></div>
  <div class="element2">
    <div id="details">
      <a>title</a>
      <button>Add TO Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using `flex-direction: column;` on `#details` and then separate the children by using `justify-content: space-between;`:

```css
.all {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  background: gray;
}

.element1 {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

.element2 {
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

#details {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#details a {
  width: 100%;
}

#details button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="element1"></div>
  <div class="element2">
    <div id="details">
      <a>title</a>
      <button>Add TO Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using flexbox, you should use it fully.

For flex items, set flex-grow: to decide their widths instead of % if you can.
As you see, using it correctly results in less code.

To have title on top and button on the bottom, use `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
.all {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
}
.element1 {
    flex-grow: 2;
    background: blue;
}
.element2 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: red;
}
#details {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#details button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="element1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="element2">
    <div id="details">
      <a>title</a>
      <button>Add TO Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```